# how to make string to object (apple interview question)

Tags: javascript, string, object

Please offers JavaScript language solution

Here is the Apple interview question:

input: `http://www.apple.com?a=1&b=2&c=3`

output:

```
{
 a:1,
 b:2,
 c:3
}
```

How to solve this question without hard code?
and

If I don't know URL constructor concept, any other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: In which language do you want the solution?

Comment: JavaScript language

Comment: You should have added "JavaScript" tag to your question. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/13944524

Answer (score 1):

That part of the URL you're looking for is called [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). There are lots of libraries in programming languages that can parse the URL and get those parameters.

Here is a Python solution:

With [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module you can parse(`urlparse`) a URL and get the information from its query string(`parse_qs`).

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = "http://www.apple.com?a=1&b=2&c=3"
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
d = {k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(parsed_url.query).items()}

print(d)
```

output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

the `[0]` part is because the values of the dictionary returned from the `parse_qs` is a list. So we get its (first) item.

Comment: Could you provide JS language solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript solution. By using the `URL` constructor on the link, you can easily access its parameters.

```js
const urlParamsToObject = (link) => {
    const url = new URL(link);

    return Object.fromEntries(url.searchParams.entries());
};

console.log(urlParamsToObject('http://www.apple.com?a=1&b=2&c=3'));
```

Is this really an Apple interview question?

**EDIT:**

It's also possible to do this without the URL constructor. Here's an example of that in TypeScript:

```
const urlParamsToObject = (link: string) => {
    const searchParams = link.split('?')[1].split('&');

    return searchParams.reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, curr) => {
        const [key, val] = curr.split('=');

        return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: decodeURIComponent(val),
        };
    }, {});
};

console.log(urlParamsToObject('http://www.apple.com?a=1&b=2&c=3'));
```

And here's an example in Python:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def url_to_params_object (link: str):
    search_params = link.split('?')[1].split('&')

    return { str.split('=')[0]: unquote(str.split('=')[1]) for str in search_params }

print(url_to_params_object('http://www.apple.com?a=1&b=2&c=3'))
```

Comment: Is this really an Apple interview question?
=> YES!!! 3000%YES

Comment: If I don't know URL constructor concept, any other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: @Lyon Check the new examples. Yes, it's possible